# How can I make easier-to-reach shortcuts for arrow keys in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

Alternate of arrow keys in **VS Code?** especially the right arrow key to move outside the double quotes without moving hand towards arrow keys.

I just want to know if there is already a shortcut available instead of key map manually.

Comment: without an example I have no clue what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use something like this in your keybindings.json (open with `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)):

```json
{
    "key": "alt+w",
    "command": "cursorUp",
    "when": "textInputFocus",
},
{
    "key": "alt+shift+w",
    "command": "cursorUpSelect",
    "when": "textInputFocus",
},
{
    "key": "alt+a",
    "command": "cursorLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus",
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+a",
    "command": "cursorWordLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus",
},
{
    "key": "alt+shift+a",
    "command": "cursorLeftSelect",
    "when": "textInputFocus",
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+a",
    "command": "cursorWordLeftSelect",
    "when": "textInputFocus",
},
{
    "key": "alt+s",
    "command": "cursorDown",
    "when": "textInputFocus",
},
{
    "key": "alt+shift+s",
    "command": "cursorDownSelect",
    "when": "textInputFocus",
},
{
    "key": "alt+d",
    "command": "cursorRight",
    "when": "textInputFocus",
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+d",
    "command": "cursorWordRight",
    "when": "textInputFocus",
},
{
    "key": "alt+shift+d",
    "command": "cursorRightSelect",
    "when": "textInputFocus",
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+d",
    "command": "cursorWordRightSelect",
    "when": "textInputFocus",
},
```

But I just remap my keys closer to the system level using AutoHotKey on Windows and xkbd on Ubuntu, which is nice because then it applies to almost all my applications.

Comment: I use AHK too. I have disabled Caps Lock and use it as an extra modifier key, allowing me to use arrow keys, backspace/delete, home/end, etc., without having to move from typing position.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a direct shortcut and achieved it using keybindings. It was fairly simple and you can also do so by following the steps below -

1. Press `Ctrl + p`
2. Type `> Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` and hit enter
3. A `keybindings.json` file should open up
4. Paste the following properties at the end of the `keybindings` file, and this should do the trick.

```
    {
      "key": "ctrl+j",
      "command": "cursorLeft",
      "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
      "key": "ctrl+k",
      "command": "cursorDown",
      "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
      "key": "ctrl+l",
      "command": "cursorRight",
      "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
      "key": "ctrl+i",
      "command": "cursorUp",
      "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
```